# Explaining some lines from the following CMD script to launch the Topcoder UML tool

Tags: java, batch-file, cmd, uml

I am trying to debug the launch script below supplied by TopCoder to start its java application for making UML diagrams.

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /d "%~dp0"

set CP=.
for /r ./lib %%V IN (*.jar) DO call :pathmunge "%%V"
call :pathmunge .\resources
call :pathmunge .\conf

start javaw -Xmx256m -cp %CP% com.topcoder.umltool.deploy.UMLToolDeploy %1 %2 %3 %4

endlocal
goto :eof

:pathmunge
set CP=%CP%;%1
```

The script is throwing errors when run from the command line.

```
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

So, I tried to dig into what this script named `run.cmd` was doing. I understand that the statement beginning with `javaw` is the one launching the application, which also needs **four arguments**. I can't find where these arguments are coming from.

Also, I understand that the `FOR` loop is recursively fetching all files from `./lib` and adding them to `Classpath`. How is it doing that? (Syntax wise)

Please let me also know the other 'fine prints' that I am missing out.

I hope I'll be able to get to the bottom of the problem using description provided in the answers.

System details: Windows 8 x64, non-administrator account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, by changing first line of batch file to `@echo on`, you could see on execution of this batch file in a command prompt window how `cmd.exe` interprets and processes this batch file line by line during execution.

The batch file first sets the current working directory to directory of the batch file which is obviously the directory of Java.

`pathmunge` is a label which is called like a function in Java. The code below `pathmunge` is the function body. In this batch file the function `pathmunge` has just 1 code line:

```
set CP=%CP%;%1
```

This is the batch code equivalent for appending a string to another string stored in an environment variable `CP` which is obviously short for *class path*.

The initial value of `CP` is just `.` which means current directory.

On every call of `pathmunge` the name of a *.jar file with full path found in subdirectory `lib` of current working directory (directory of batch file) or one of its subdirectories is appended after a semi-colon.

The file name is appended in double quotes in case of 1 or more spaces in name of the *.jar file with complete path. That is not really correct as the entire class path string on running `javaw.exe` should be enclosed in double quotes instead of each *.jar file.

`%1` in function `pathmunge` references first function parameter - the name of the *.jar file passed from `FOR` loop on calling `pathmunge`.

Depending on number of *.jar files in subdirectory `lib` of the directory of the batch file, the string in environment variable `CP` can become very long, too long for being processed by `cmd.exe`, see [Command prompt (Cmd. exe) command-line string limitation](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/830473).

**This is your problem. There are too many *.jar files which are with complete path appended to a very long string being finally too long for being processed further.**

Appended to *class path* directory list string are also the two subdirectories `resources` and `conf` with relative path.

With `%1 %2 %3 %4` the string values of the first 4 parameters used on starting the batch file are referenced for being passed to `javaw.exe` as parameters. If you have just double clicked on the batch file, those 4 variables are empty.

Better would be following code (most likely because not tested by me with Java):

```
@echo off
setlocal

cd /D "%~dp0"

set "CP=."
for /R .\lib %%V in (*.jar) do call :pathmunge "%%V"
call :pathmunge .\resources
call :pathmunge .\conf

start "" javaw.exe -Xmx256m -cp "%CP%" com.topcoder.umltool.deploy.UMLToolDeploy %*

endlocal
goto :EOF

:pathmunge
set "CP=%CP%;%~1"
```

Instead of appending name of each *.jar file with complete path in double quotes to `CP`, now the complete file names are appended without double quotes and instead the entire class path string is enclosed in double quotes on running `javaw.exe`.

And all parameters specified on starting the batch file are now passed to `javaw.exe` independent on their number because of `%*` instead of `%1 %2 %3 %4`.

It may help to avoid appending the *.jar files in subdirectory `lib` and its subdirectories with relative path instead of complete path. That makes the *class path* string much shorter. The batch code below appends the *.jar files with relative path.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "UmlToolDirectory=%~dp0"
cd /D "%UmlToolDirectory%"

set "CP=."
for /R .\lib %%V in (*.jar) do (
    set "LibraryFile=%%V"
    set "LibraryFile=!LibraryFile:%UmlToolDirectory%=.\!"
    call :pathmunge "!LibraryFile!"
)
call :pathmunge .\resources
call :pathmunge .\conf

start "" javaw.exe -Xmx256m -cp "%CP%" com.topcoder.umltool.deploy.UMLToolDeploy %*

endlocal
goto :EOF

:pathmunge
set "CP=%CP%;%~1"
```

If you want to know more about one of those commands, open a command prompt window and run the command with parameter `/?` like

```
call /?
cd /?
for /?
goto /?
set /?
setlocal /?
start /?
```